# Dual of $Cc(X)$ with LB-Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, duality-theorems, dual-spaces

I'm currently reading on the Riesz-Markov Representation Theorem which identifies *positive linear functionals* with certain Radon measures.  However, in the project I'm working on, I'm dealing with a *slightly different* LCS.  Namely, let $X$ be a $\sigma$-compact metric space with nested compact cover $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and let $C_c(X)$ be the locally-convex space (LCS) whose topology is the colimit in the LCS category of the spaces:
$$
\iota_n: C(X_n)\hookrightarrow C(X_{n+1}),
$$
where $\iota_n$ is the inclusion.

---

According to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220511/questions-on-topologies-on-space-of-radon-measures), the continuous dual of $C_c(X)$ is isometrically isomorphic with the set of Radon measure $M(X)$ with the total variation topology.

---

What exactly is the isomophism from:
$$
C_c(X)'\mapsto M(X)?
$$
*(Concretely in this direction).*  Moreover, where can I read-up about it?

Comment: There is a paper by Dieudonne and Schwartz that deals quite a lot with the duals of such spaces. I don't have it here but you may be able to find the necessary statements to see the result in that paper. One thing the paper shows is that the continuous functionals on such a space are the same as the sequentially continuous functionals and you can explicitly characterise all convergent sequences in your space.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks; I hope it has a 'concrete' description of the isomorphism (since otherwise I may not be able to use this result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the paper I meant in the comment: http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1949__1__61_0.pdf

The paper is in french but that shouldn't stop you from reading it, even if you (like me) dont know any french. Here is a rough sketch of how you can use the results of the paper:

The topology you define makes $C_c(X)$ into a strict LF space (what the paper just calls LF space) - this is explained by Example 1 on page 67. By a Proposition 5 of Dieudonné and Schwartz a linear map (valued in a locally convex space) is continuous iff its restriction to $C_c(X_m)$ is continuous for every $m$.

Now verify that a (signed) Radon measure on $X$ induces a continuous map on every $C_c(X_m)$ by restriction. Further the Riesz Markov theorem tells you that the only continuous functionals on $C_c(X_m)$ ($X_m$ compact) are the signed Radon measures on $X_m$. At this point it becomes an exercise to show that the only consistent way to glue such measures together is by having them be a restriction of a measure on all of $X$.

The isomorphism

$$M(X)\to C_c(X)'$$
is given by
$$\mu\mapsto [f\mapsto \int_X fd\mu]$$

if we want to see why its a topological isomorphism we need to understand the topology of the dual of an LF space. Dieudonné and Schwartz give it  the topology of uniform convergence on bounded sets - here a set in $C_c(X)$ is called bounded iff it is contained entirely in a bounded subset of a $C_c(X_m)$ (see Proposition 4 - I believe borné means bounded).

So you can get the topology on the dual generated by the semi-norms:

$$|\varphi|_m := \sup_{f\in C_c(X_m), \|f\|≤1} |\varphi(f)|$$

Comment: This does help, I really appreciate the isomorphism too (I figured it may look something like this in the direction $M(X)\mapsto C_c(X)'$.  So, in the converse direction I guess we obtain a measure by acting on "mollifications" of compact subsets of $X$ and then using then noting that this implies inner/outer regularity somehow (so the resulting measure should be Radon)?  (P.s.: Yes borné means bounded...I just realized.. the term bornology comes from it.)